# Segmentation fault in Qt Designer 4.6 with custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, segmentation-fault, qt-designer

I had a segmentation fault when using my new Qt Widget with Qt Designer 4.6. The problem arise when trying to preview the new widget.

when using gdb I found that the problem is in qdesigner_internal::WidgetFactory::applyStyleToTopLevel:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
qdesigner_internal::WidgetFactory::applyStyleToTopLevel (style=0x0, widget=0x1829df0) at /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/widgetfactory.cpp:777
777 /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/widgetfactory.cpp: No such file or directory.
 in /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/widgetfactory.cpp
(gdb) bt
#0  qdesigner_internal::WidgetFactory::applyStyleToTopLevel (style=0x0, widget=0x1829df0) at /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/widgetfactory.cpp:777
#1  0x00007ffff7475bed in qdesigner_internal::QDesignerFormBuilder::createPreview (fw=, styleName=..., appStyleSheet=..., deviceProfile=, scriptErrors=
    0x7fffffffbee0, errorMessage=0x7fffffffc3f0) at /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/qdesigner_formbuilder.cpp:404
#2  0x00007ffff7476773 in qdesigner_internal::QDesignerFormBuilder::createPreview (fw=0x0, styleName=..., appStyleSheet=..., deviceProfile=..., errorMessage=0x0)
    at /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/qdesigner_formbuilder.cpp:439
#3  0x00007ffff7532b27 in qdesigner_internal::PreviewManager::createPreview (this=0x837f20, fw=0x1879200, pc=..., deviceProfileIndex=-1, errorMessage=0x7fffffffc3f0, initialZoom=-1)
    at /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/previewmanager.cpp:686
#4  0x00007ffff75343cf in qdesigner_internal::PreviewManager::showPreview (this=0x837f20, fw=0x1879200, pc=..., deviceProfileIndex=-1, errorMessage=0x7fffffffc3f0)
    at /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/previewmanager.cpp:760
#5  0x00007ffff753472f in qdesigner_internal::PreviewManager::showPreview (this=0x837f20, fw=0x1879200, style=..., deviceProfileIndex=-1, errorMessage=0x7fffffffc3f0)
    at /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.6.0/tools/designer/src/lib/shared/previewmanager.cpp:659
```

because a null pointer was passed there:

```
void WidgetFactory::applyStyleToTopLevel(QStyle *style, QWidget *widget)
{
    const QPalette standardPalette = style->standardPalette();
    if (widget->style() == style && widget->palette() == standardPalette)
        return;
//....
}
```

I'm new in Qt and this is my first custom widget. does anybody have a clue for solving this.

here is my widget code

```
MBICInput::MBICInput(QWidget *parent) : QStackedWidget(parent){
  displayPage = new QWidget();
  displayPage->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("displayPage"));

  inputLB = new QLabel(displayPage);
  inputLB->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("inputLabel"));
  inputLB->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor));

  addWidget(displayPage);

  EditPage = new QWidget();
  EditPage->setProperty("EditInputLine", QVariant(true));
  EditPage->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("EditPage"));

  inputInput = new QLineEdit(EditPage);
  inputInput->setGeometry(QRect(5, 10, 231, 25));
  inputInput->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("input"));

  addWidget(EditPage);

  _animation = new QString("");
  _message   = new QString("Message");
  _validator = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[a-zA-Z]+"), this);

}

MBICInput::~MBICInput() {
}

QValidator::State MBICInput::validate(QString &text, int &pos) const{
    return _validator->validate(text, pos);
}

void MBICInput::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
  QPainter painter(this);
  painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
}


QSize MBICInput::minimumSizeHint() const{
   return QSize(200, 40);
}

QSize MBICInput::sizeHint() const{
   return QSize(200, 40);
}

void MBICInput::setAnimation(const QString &animation){
  *_animation = animation;
  update();
}

QString MBICInput::animation() const{
   return *_animation;
}

void MBICInput::setMessage(const QString &message){
  *_message = message;
  update();
}

QString MBICInput::message() const{
   return *_message;
}

void MBICInput::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
  if(currentIndex()==0){
    setCurrentIndex(1);
  }else{
    setCurrentIndex(0);
  }
   update();
}
```

Comment: When you're previewing the widget, which style are you using?  What operating system are you running designer on?

Answer (score 0):

In the `applyStyleToTopLevel` function, you are using the widget pointers without verifying it's a valid pointer. So when doing `widget->style` with a `NULL` widget pointer it will crash.

Comment: Yes, I know that, the problem is that the function applyStyleToTopLevel is not mine, it's the Qt Designer source code. My question is, what in my code has triggered such error ??

Answer (score 0):

Just for information I just compiled the same code under the Qt version 4.5.3-9 and it worked just fine with the 4.5 designer. may be it's a Qt 4.6 bug...